# Excel VBA Regex Function That Returns Multiple Matches Into A Single Cell

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I need help getting my Excel function to work. The goal is to run an in-cell function that extracts all pattern matches of a regex function from the input of another cell into one cell, not an array of cells.

I have tried this using an array which returns two matches in the function dialogue box preview but only outputs the first match in the cell. I have also tried using a collection but had no luck with that.

Here is my current code and a sample of text that would be used as the function's string input:

```
Function RegexMatches(strInput As String) As Variant

Dim rMatch As Match
Dim arrayMatches
Dim i As Long

arrayMatches = Array()

With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(Code)[\s][\d]{2,4}"
        For Each rMatch In .Execute(strInput)
        ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
        arrayMatches(i) = rMatch.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
End With

    RegexMatches = arrayMatches
End Function
```

Sample strInput from an Excel cell:

*Code 123 some random text

goes here and continues to the next line

Code 4567 followed by more text

including new lines not just wrapped text*



The desired output from this function would be both (2) matched values from the regex function into a **single cell** (e.g. "Code 123 Code 4567").

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Concat the match values, and then return this trimmed string.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Check out this [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/CugeElc.png?1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is what I was thinking conceptually but I don't know how to do it inside the function using VBA code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the insight, I missed the last three lines of the copy/paste. I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you missed off the end of your function (as per Mat's Mug's comment)? Try this (which is as per Wiktor's comment).

Edit: amended in light of Mat's Mug's suggestion.

```
Function RegexMatches(strInput As String) As String

Dim rMatch As Object
Dim s As String
Dim arrayMatches()
Dim i As Long

With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(Code)[\s][\d]{2,4}"
    If .test(strInput) Then
        For Each rMatch In .Execute(strInput)
            ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
            arrayMatches(i) = rMatch.Value
            i = i + 1
            's = s & " " & rMatch
        Next
    End If
End With

RegexMatches = Join(arrayMatches, " ")

End Function
```

Comment: I'd make the function return an array of matches as the name implies (`Variant` was fine then), and use `Join` at the call site to join the values with a `vbNewLine` to get the string to dump into the cell.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - thanks, have amended. I agree it is a more elegant approach.

Comment: Except you're doing the `Join` *in* the function now (returns a `String`); `RegexMatches = arrayMatches`, and let the caller deal with the string representation ;-)

Comment: Oh duh, just realized the function is actually used as a UDF!

Comment: @Mat's Mug - what's the issue with Join? Because the OP wants the results in a single cell, will your suggestion work?

Comment: Nothing - the fact that the function was called by a cell had eluded me; joining before returning, and returning a `String`, is exactly what the OP needs =)   if it was just an ordinary function, it being responsible for both the matching and the string representation would be violating SRP IMO.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I did some exploratory learning first before posting but nothing returned the desired result. This is perfect!

Comment: @Mat's Mug - ah I see, ok, thanks again for the suggestion. user7196523 - my pleasure.

Comment: @SJR is it possible to replace the space delimiter in the JOIN function with a new line instead so that the output would be the equivalent of an Alt+Enter inside the output cell after each matched value? `RegexMatches = Join(arrayMatches, vbNewLine)` obviously does not work but this is the concept I am going for.

Comment: I think it does work, but you have to turn on text wrapping.

Comment: How critical is it to .test(strInput) before .Execute(strInput)? I am not suggesting, just curious.

Comment: @SJR , I see `i` has been used on a loop without setting initial value for it, Is that means the default value for (long data type) is 0 ?

Comment: @DrPhil  - without testing it will error if no match is found.

Comment: @Leedo - yes that is correct.

Comment: @SJR, it doesn't error. Your for each loop handles it fine.