# How can I have my Access VBA regex return all possible matches instead of only the first match?

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

This is my current code, it is only returning the first match, I need to return all matches. Example, [phone number 1] & [phone number 2] & [phone number 3]... but it is only returning [phone number 1].

```
Public Function X_FIND( _
    ByVal SourceString As String, _
    ByVal Pattern As String, _
Optional ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal MatchGlobal As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim re As New regexp
        re.MultiLine = MultiLine
        re.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        re.Global = MatchGlobal
        re.Pattern = Pattern
    Dim m
    For Each m In re.Execute(SourceString)
        X_FIND = m.Value
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Concatenate your values inside your loop, then set X_FIND to that concatenated value after the loop. Better yet [toss the matches into an array and JOIN() the array at the end for your output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979363/excel-vba-regex-function-that-returns-multiple-matches-into-a-single-cell/44979561). The way you have it written now, you return the first match as the function return and then... your subsequent loops are ignored.

Comment: Also, make sure Global is set to `True`.

Comment: I kind-of know what you mean, do you mind typing that? Sorry im a visual person so I want to see exactly what you mean. And I believe global is set to true?

Comment: @CoderTanner The default value is `True` for `Global`, but you can override it to `False` in the 5th parameter of `X_FIND`. Double check you aren't.

Comment: @JNevill Can you explain what you mean joining an array? Do you have an example?

Comment: "Joining" an array here and in most languages is where you take a single dim array and turn it into a single string where each value of the array is in the string delimited by some character. So an array like `myArr=ARRAY(1,2,3,4)` that we join with `JOIN(myArr, ",")` will result in a string like `1,2,3,4` that can be returned  here. You could also return the array itself, which might be the better solution depending on what your caller code needs.

Comment: @JNevill  Okay that makes sense, im super new to functions so im just struggling to figure out how to implement an array and a join into the existing function. Do you have any links or anything so I can learn more about it. I just need to create the function for work purposes.

Comment: Might help to provide sample source data. And exactly how you are calling the function.

Comment: @June7 So im calling the function from a query, "X_FIND(STRING_SOURCE,PATTERN). and the query that im calling it from is a memo field with multiple possibilities. For this example ill say im just going to be finding phone numbers. In the memo field there could be o to 500 possible phone number patterns. So I want to gather all of them in one field concatenated together like JNevill was talking about. like "111-111-1111, 222-222-2222, etc." hope that helps! Thanks!

Comment: @CoderTanner Why do you want to use regex? As you mentioned, you have 0 to 500 possible phone number patterns and want to gather all of them in one field, so do you want phone number with specific patterns or just all in one string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed 1 line in the function:

`X_FIND = X_FIND & "," & m.value`

I tested the function with inputs:

```
Mid(X_FIND("999-999-9998 abckd 999-999-9999", "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"),2)
```

Returns string:

`999-999-9998,999-999-9999`

If there is possibility of duplicate phone numbers, use pattern:
`"([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})(?!.*?\1.*$)"`

Only the last match of each unique value will be returned.

If you want to assure returns are in ascending order, will require more code, which is not simple as far as I can see, and involves writing the unique matches to array (this is easy with Split function) or collection and applying bubble sort or some other algorithm (this is the complicated part).

Comment: It works! wow thanks! It gives me exactly what I needed so thank you! Do you know how I could make it so it doesnt have any duplicate returns? Example: 
"999-999-9998 abckd 999-999-9999 asdf 999-999-9998" to return "999-999-9998,999-999-9999". Maybe just an if statement in the "x_FIND =" Formula maybe?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!