# Excel VBA regex pattern giving error '5018'

Tags: excel, regex, vba

Im trying to extract size from product details by using the below REGEX..

```
With rgx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "([0-9.,*?/]+{1,5}\s*(g|G|ML|ml|mL|Ml|oz|OZ|Oz|ea|\s+)){1,3}"
    
    Set temp = .Execute(Rng)
```

However, while executing the regex im facing 5018 error in line **Set temp = .Execute(Rng)**
Why im getting this error anything wrong in h eregex?

Comment: What is `Rng`? Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: Try `.Execute(Rng.Value2)`

Comment: Rng is the cell value example values can be Size:1.70 oz, size:100ml, size 10.5g or size:100 ml + 50 ml

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/62456/why-does-my-regular-expressions-invoke-error-5018-in-my-vba-script-in-excel

Comment: But `+{1,5}` is wrong syntax too. The `+` is not quantifiable in this case. You'd probably just want to remove the "+" alltogether. Then again, if you explain a bit more what you are after, there may be a better pattern here.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i tried but not working..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its a string only

Comment: If you are passing a string value, then see what @JvdV suggested about changing your pattern. See the link that I posted above. How you can get the error if your pattern is incorrect.

Comment: @JvdV thank yes you are correct now working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/62456/why-does-my-regular-expressions-invoke-error-5018-in-my-vba-script-in-excel), 5018 stands for **"Unexpected quantifier in regular expression"**.

Look at `[0-9.,*?/]+{1,5}` where there is `+{1,5}`, two quantifiers at a row.

In VBA regex this is an error.

If you match 1 to 5 characters belonging to the `[0-9.,*?/]` set, use `[0-9.,*?/]{1,5}`.

If you match one or more, use `[0-9.,*?/]+`.

*Do not chain quantifiers*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. One clarification if i want to capture Size where 100 ml + 20 ml what could be the pattern (regex) for it?

Comment: @Linga Your expression looks good, note how to extract all matches at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979363/excel-vba-regex-function-that-returns-multiple-matches-into-a-single-cell. Expression like `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\s*(g|G|ML|ml|mL|Ml|oz|OZ|Oz|ea)` could work for you.